# Segmentation fault in x86 example program

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, ld, gnu-assembler

I'm reading this book *Programming From the Ground Up*, Jonathan Bartlett. On this program that shows the function calling conventions for the first time I'm getting a segmentation fault when running it after typing it just like in the book. The function just takes 2 numbers from the stack, and returns the first number to the second number power in %eax.

Here is the program in question:

```
.code32

.section .data

.section .text

.globl _start
_start:

  pushl $3
  pushl $2
  call power
  addl $8, %esp

  pushl %eax

  pushl $2
  pushl $5
  call power
  addl $8, %esp

  popl %ebx

  addl %eax, %ebx

  movl $1, %eax
  int $0x80

.type power, @function
power:
  pushl %ebp
  movl %esp, %ebp
  subl $4, %esp

  movl 8(%ebp),  %ebx
  movl 12(%ebp), %ecx

  movl %ebx, -4(%ebp)

power_loop:
  cmpl $1, %ecx
  je end_power

  movl -4(%ebp), %eax
  imull %ebx, %eax
  movl %eax, -4(%ebp)
  decl %ecx

  jmp power_loop

end_power:
  movl -4(%ebp), %eax
  movl %ebp, %esp
  popl %ebp
  ret
```

I loaded the program in edb and stepped through it, and the segmentation fault appears when I get to the instruction that loads the first function argument. Giving the error message saying

*The address 0x000000003EC56208 could not be accessed.*

Shouldn't I be able to access the values pointed by (8 + %ebp) and (12 + %ebp) inside the function?

Comment: Are you certain that the stack is being set up for you properly? Are you sure it *is* being set up for you? What assembler do you use? How do you assemble it? How do you link it?

Comment: I just use 'as' and 'ld' like the book says. How would I be able to tell how the stack is being set up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you want to build a 32-bit program on a 64-bit operating system. You have to tell assembler and linker about that circumstance:

```
as --32 -o power.o power.s
ld -m elf_i386 -o power power.o
```

Run it with `./power`.

Comment: That worked, thanks! I thought the .code32 directive told it that.